# Getting SMART information from Disks behind Adaptec 51645 using smartctl

Tags: raid, windows-server-2012

according to https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Supported_RAID-Controllers I should be able to query my HDDs behind an Adaptec 51645 with smartctl higher than 6.4

I'm running 6.6, but have no luck:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> smartctl -a -d aacraid,0,0,1 /dev/sda
smartctl 6.6 2017-11-05 r4594 [x86_64-w64-mingw32-2012] (sf-6.6-1)
Copyright (C) 2002-17, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

ERROR: smartctl takes ONE device name as the final command-line argument.
You have provided 4 device names:
0
0
1
/dev/sda

Use smartctl -h to get a usage summary
```

Is there something I'm overlooking? I it possible to get the SMART information any other way, except the horrible Adaptec Storage Manager?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it now. It a little facepalm moment for me, but perhaps I can help anybody with this:

```
smartctl -a -d "aacraid,0,0,1" /dev/sda
```